# What is the meaning of "as such" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

what is the meaning of ''as such'' in this text?

> Fourier series are infinite series that represent periodic functions in terms of cosines and
> sines. **As such**, Fourier series are of greatest importance to the engineer and applied
> mathematician.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary defintion (Cambridge) gives "as being what is indicated or suggested".

So it means "As "infinite series that represent periodic functions in terms of cosines and sines", Fourier series are of greatest importance ..."

or even more explicitly,  "Because Fourier series are infinite series that represent periodic functions in terms of cosines and sines, they are of greatest importance..."